# Given an array of numbers, return array of products of all other numbers (with division)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

```
Given an array of numbers, nums, return an array of 
numbers products, where products[i] is the product of 
all nums[j], j != i.

Input : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output: [(2*3*4*5), (1*3*4*5), (1*2*4*5), (1*2*3*5), 
         (1*2*3*4)]
      = [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]
```

You must do this in O(N) WITH using division.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] outPut = new int[arr.length]; 
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    int res=Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
    outPut[i] = res/arr[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outPut));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] output = new int[arr.length];

int product = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    product *= arr[i];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    output[i] = product / arr[i];
    System.out.println(output[i]);
}
```

Overall time complexity is O(n).

Here's the link where I tested this: http://ideone.com/dDVwrO

Steps:

1. First calculate the product of all numbers.
2. For each `i`, divide the product obtained in (1) with `arr[i]` and put the result in the output array.